# Adjust center map to the fragment width

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

In one app that I'm developing I have to show a little map (in pixels it will be 250x250 or something like that) with the center as the coordinates that the user previously selected, in the onCreateView of the fragment I get the new Lat and Lng and I set the camera and a marker in this point but the map view is not centered because if I drag the map a little to the left I can reveal the marker, placed in the correct spot.

How can I center the map to new Lat and Lng according to the fragment's width and height?

That's the code I'm using to center the map, in a bigger view, the map center is correct but in a smaller view the center gets a little moved to the right.

```
mapa.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posMap, 11));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just center the map to marker? Like that:

```
 map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapLoaded() {
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lng)).title(markerTitle));
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 14));
                    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }
            });
```

where **lat** and **lng** are respectively double values of your marker latitude and longitude.

Comment: Nope, it does the same as my code. A little moved to the right.

Comment: Is it possible that you post a screenshot? Maybe you have some kind of overlay on the map which makes a part of it not visible? We had similar situation once in one of our applications (basically map was in a expanding panel), and we were adjusting the offset of the camera on our own.

Comment: never mind I figured out what's the problem, the fragment was not properly set up in the LinearLayout so adding the proper width, height and weight to the FrameLayout fixed the problem. Thanks anyway!